# Broadcasting Library in react native that support rtmp server url

Tags: react-native, rtmp, live-streaming, broadcasting

I am looking for a library in react native to broadcast or go live from mobile which support rtmp server url for broadcasting

I have tried `react-native-rtmp-publisher` and `react-native-nodemediaclient` libraries, where `react-native-rtmp-publisher` has a disconnection issue and `react-native-nodemediaclient` is not working in IOS.